# WebSocket onmessage is not triggered when onsend is called

Tags: react-native, redux, websocket, serverless

I am developing a stateless typescript backend with WebSocket. I created a SocketMiddleware as a middleware to my redux state based on [dev.io tutorial](https://dev.to/aduranil/how-to-use-websockets-with-redux-a-step-by-step-guide-to-writing-understanding-connecting-socket-middleware-to-your-project-km3). The first `socket.send()` message from `onopen` works fine. However, I can't trigger the subsequent `onmessage` using `SEND_MSG` dispatch.

The backend shows that it receives a `log` but it is not received by the clients. I am sure that the `connection_id` is already set correctly

```
const socketMiddleware = () => {
  let socket = null;

  const onOpen = (store) => (event) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "WS_CONNECTED" });
  };

  const onClose = (store) => () => {
    store.dispatch({ type: "WS_DISCONNECTED" });
  };

  const onMessage = (store) => (message) => {
    console.log("message received @middleware, ", message.data);
    const payload = JSON.parse(message.data);
    switch (payload.action) {
      case "get_connection_id":
        const { connectionId } = payload;
        store.dispatch({
          type: "UPDATE_MY_CONNECTION_ID",
          payload: { myConnectionId: connectionId },
        });
        break;
      case "join_room_socket":
        const { match_id, players, connectionIdArr } = payload;
        if (match_id) {
          store.dispatch({
            type: "UPDATE_ROOM",
            payload: {
              players: players,
              match_id: match_id,
              connectionIdArr: connectionIdArr,
            },
          });
        }
        break;
      case "broadcast_action":
        const { move } = body;
        store.dispatch({
          type: "UPDATE_GAME_STATE",
          payload: { move: move },
        });
    }
  };
  return (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "WS_CONNECT":
        if (socket !== null) socket.close();
        socket = new WebSocket(process.env.WSS_ENDPOINT);
        socket.onmessage = onMessage(store);
        socket.onclose = onClose(store);
        socket.onopen = onOpen(store);
        break;
      case "WS_CONNECTED":
        console.log("WebSocket client is connected");
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({ action: "get_connection_id" }));
      case "WS_DISCONNECTED":
        console.log("WebSocket client is disconnected");
      case "SEND_MSG":
        console.log("sending a message", action);
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({ ...action.payload }));
      default:
        console.log("the next action:", action);
        return next(action);
    }
  };
};

export default socketMiddleware();
```

my redux store

```
...
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk, wsMiddleware))
);
```

my backend side:

```
  joinRoomSocket: (data) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(data.body);
    body.connectionIdArr.map((connectionId) => {
      const endpoint = `${data.requestContext.domainName}/${data.requestContext.stage}`;
      const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
        apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
        endpoint,
      });
      const params = {
        ConnectionId: connectionId,
        Data: JSON.stringify(body),
      };
      return apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise();
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Which onmessage are you referring to server or client? If you are referring to onMessage callback of client. For this you need to send something from the server using websocket.send('text message').

For client to receive message on onmessage event, server needs to send data.
Here is the flow:

````
Client ws.onsend('abc') ----------------> Server ws.onmessage(data)
Server ws.onsend('abc') ----------------> Client ws.onmessage(data)```
````

Comment: I was referring to client's onMessage callback. I have updated my question with the backend WebSocket. It looks quite different from expressJS, thus my confusion.

Comment: For client to receive message on onmessage event, server needs to send data.
Here is the flow:

```Client ws.onsend('abc') ----------------> Server ws.onmessage(data)
Server ws.onsend('abc') ----------------> Client ws.onmessage(data)```